# How to get the middle 5 digits of a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing a little project and I essentially need to figure out the middle 5 digits of a number (e.g. `123454321` would return `34543`). If the number is 4 digits (e.g. `1234`) it will return the middle two (in the case of `1234` this would be `23`). If the number is 3 digits, it will return the middle number (e.g. `123` would return `2`), and if the number is 1 or 2 digits the code won't accept the input.

I've tried doing some research about this online, but haven't really managed to find anything other than the ["Middle-square method"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-square_method) but the [implementation for python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-square_method#Example_Implementation) they have doesn't seem to work.

```py
num = 730945296 #Random number for testing

num_len = len(str(num))
print(num*num) #debug 
print(str(num*num).zfill(num_len)) #debug
num = int(str(num*num).zfill(num_len)[round(num_len/4):round((num_len/4)*3)])


print(num)
```

is my representation of the [implementation for python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-square_method#Example_Implementation) but as I stated above, this doesn't seem to work.

In this case the output was `9452` but I expected `09452`.

I'm aware I'm not doing extra checks like whether output is more than 5 digits or how long input is but I figured I should concentrate on getting the middle digits first.

Comment: What does middle square have anything to do with this?

Comment: What if your number has an even number of digits? What's the middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The reason you are not getting `0` at the beginning of the answer, is that you are storing the value as `int`. Try using string as a number and the problem will be a piece of cake.